# how to assign shards which are actual unassigned?

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

Problem: I've started five elasticsearch nodes, but only 66,84 % of the Data is in kibana available. When I check the cluster health with  localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true I've got the following informations: `{
  "cluster_name" : "A2A",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 5,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 4,
  "active_primary_shards" : 612,
  "active_shards" : 613,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 304,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 66.8484187568157
}`

And also all my indices are red, except of the kibana index.

Small Part:

`red    open   logstash-2015.11.08   5   0      47256          668     50.5mb         50.5mb 
red    open   logstash-2015.11.09   5   0      46540         1205     50.4mb         50.4mb 
red    open   logstash-2015.11.06   5   0      65645          579     69.2mb         69.2mb 
red    open   logstash-2015.11.07   5   0      62733          674     66.4mb         66.4mb 
green  open   .kibana               1   1          2            0     19.7kb          9.8kb 
red    open   logstash-2015.11.11   5   0      49254         1272       53mb           53mb 
red    open   logstash-2015.11.12   5   0      50885          466     53.6mb         53.6mb 
red    open   logstash-2015.11.10   5   0      49174         1288     52.6mb         52.6mb 
red    open   logstash-2016.04.12   5   0      92508          585    104.8mb        104.8mb 
red    open   logstash-2016.04.13   5   0      95120          279    107.2mb        107.2mb`

I've tried to fix the problem with `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_settings' -d ' {"index.routing.allocation.disable_allocation": false}'` but it doesn't work!

So has anyone of you some ideas how to assign my shards?

And when you need some other infos please ask and I will try to offer you the data:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816954/1834331

You could also try restarting elasticsearch first: `service elasticsearch restart`.

Otherwise, just try reallocating the shards manually (as your indices have 5 shards, run the command with the `shard` flag `0`, `1`, `2`, .. `5`):

```
curl -XPOST -d '{ "commands" : [ {
  "allocate" : {
       "index" : "logstash-2015.11.08", 
       "shard" : 0, 
       "node" : "SOME_NODE_HERE",
       "allow_primary":true 
     } 
  } ] }' http://localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute?pretty`
```

You can check the nodes with unassigned shards using: `curl -s localhost:9200/_cat/shards | grep UNASS`

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  this was the answer i searched for :)

Answer (score 0):

if shards are stuck in unallocated they can be manually allocated.  For example:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute' -d '{
    "commands": [{
        "allocate": {
            "index": "logstash-2015.11.07",
            "shard": 5,
            "node": "Frederick Slade",
            "allow_primary": 1
        }
    }]
}'
```

See the [Cluster Reroute](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html) documentation, including warnings on the use of `allow_primary`.