# Elasticsearch: what does "shard allocation" mean?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

We encountered a production incident, that Elasticsearch cluster health check returned `red` status. The health check report shows `marvel-2019.06.20` has 2 unassigned_shards, which seems the root cause.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health?level=indices&pretty'

{
  "cluster_name" : "sap-jam-jam8",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 122,
  "active_shards" : 239,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 7,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "indices" : {
     ...
     ...
     ".marvel-2019.06.20" : {
          "status" : "red",
          "number_of_shards" : 1,
          "number_of_replicas" : 1,
          "active_primary_shards" : 0,
          "active_shards" : 0,
          "relocating_shards" : 0,
          "initializing_shards" : 0,
          "unassigned_shards" : 2
    }
  }
```

we checked the config of Elasticseach, found `cluster.routing.allocation` has been disabled.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty'
{
  "persistent" : { },
  "transient" : {
    "cluster" : {
      "routing" : {
        "allocation" : {
          "enable" : "none"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816954/5117552) suggested, we forced a shard to be assigned, and this issue has gone.

```
curl -XPOST -d '{ "commands" : [ {
  "allocate" : {
       "index" : ".marvel-2014.05.21", 
       "shard" : 0, 
       "node" : "SOME_NODE_HERE",
       "allow_primary":true 
     } 
  } ] }' http://localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute?pretty
```

---

After resolved this incident, I think it's necessary to figure out the basic concept `shard allocation`. I did some research, but the following questions are still confusing for me.

### 1. Why elasticsearch needs to `assign shard` to other nodes?

In my case, we have two elasticsearch nodes, A and B. Two shards have already been created in A, and consumed disk space.

When B is not available, why not just active those two shards in server A?

At least it return a `yellow` health status.

### 2. What's the procedures of `assign a shard`?

In the first question, we suppose both primary shard and replica has been created in server A. when saying `assign shard to B`, what does that mean?

Doest that mean copy shard from server A to server B?

### 3. How to explain this zero active shard?

Both primary shard and replicate has been created, but are not active. How is it possible? Besides disk storage, is there other overhead to activate a shard? e.g. Memory?

```
".marvel-2019.06.20" : {
  "status" : "red",
  "number_of_shards" : 1,
  "number_of_replicas" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0, // both shards are inactive.
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 2
}
```

### 4. Is the following assumption true?

To make a shard active, Elasticsearch need do the following steps:

- Create a shard.
- Find a server, which has enough disk space and RAM to run it.
- copy this shard from source server to destination server.
- Activate this shard.

### Reference

1. [Elasticsearch blog: Red Elasticsearch Cluster? Panic no longer](https://www.elastic.co/blog/red-elasticsearch-cluster-panic-no-longer?nsukey=rugJ0ULHhuAevjmDVw9V7DcHpPoz%2FE8cPo8PzjUhWPGEBBeuPbl7KmJWrKATv16Ao7uTcN4zQ5WefcbmoKSkn%2F2BZyMo9fa7eSrIZDJKfyn7BlIQWFuc5WiS3z2YZ3JRkdWGLrjUAsP9qMORklgpI9ItHwU%2BteEWb%2FjX5oCxf7zMmEnEoZO13%2FiCk1oEltp5eCgo14qYVv7tsGArWgM4Sg%3D%3D)
2. [Stack overflow: elasticsearch - what to do with unassigned shards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816954/5117552)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but are some thoughts:

1. You have 2 node cluster. ES will try to allocate shards on both nodes to provide HA in case that one of the node fails (and even for better read/write performance)
2. Related to 1. ES tries to allocate shards accros nodes to provide HA. If both shards are allocated on node A and you add node B to cluster ES will try to move replica shards to B.
3. Only index is created, not shards. So it tells you "ok, I've managed to create index but I can't find where to place its data". You can find why by running `cat shards` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-shards.html). Shards do cost memory as theirs metadata has to be cached.
4. That's probably procedure for adding replica shards with possible few additional conditions (like try to create replica on node which doesn't contain primary shard and which has least load and can contain data...)