# Add non existing cluster settings in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Recently i have built elasticsearch with fluentd and Kibana and all is working fine, but we are facing high cpu load while performing search caused by java.

I have 60 GB Ram and 16 processors and each processor has 2 cores.

> ES_HEAP_SIZE=32g

-find below more details

```
curl "localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool?v&h=search.rejected"
```

> search.rejected 
>               387

```
curl "localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool?v&h=index.rejected"
```

> index.rejected 
>                0

- snapshot from elasticsearch.log

> [DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Hulk 2099]
>   [logstash-2015.03.14][4], node[qxcAN3lURs65Lf1GMhB_qg], [P],
>   s[STARTED]: Failed to execute
>   [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@7c71025f] lastShard
>   [true] 
>   org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsRejectedExecutionException:
>   rejected execution (queue capacity 1000) on
>   org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23@1d7c9f0f
>
> ```
>     at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsAbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(EsAbortPolicy.java:62)
>
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
>
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
>
>     at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.execute(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:551)
>
>     at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteQuery(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:228)
>
>     at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchCountAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchCountAction.java:71)
>
>     at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:171)
> ```

Now i read that i have to update the threadpool settings in ES and i have now

```
 curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty
```

> {   "persistent" : { },    "transient" : { }  }

i'm trying to update the settings with the below commands

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ 

"threadpool" : {    "index": { 
    "type": "fixed", 
    "size": 32, 
    "queue_size": 1000    },    "bulk": { 
    "type": "fixed", 
    "size": 32, 
    "queue_size": 1000    },    "search": { 
    "type": "fixed", 
    "size": 96, 
    "queue_size": 1000   }  }  }'
```

but i keep getting

> {"error":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no
>   settings to update;]","status":400}

What's wrong with this command? is it the right solution for my issue ?

Please advise

Thanks.

Ayman

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify if the updates are `permanent` (applied across all restarts) or `transient` (will not survive a full cluster restart). Find more information [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html).

If you want to apply your settings transiently, use the command below:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ 
    "transient": {
        "threadpool": {
            "index": {
                "type": "fixed",
                "size": 32,
                "queue_size": 1000
            },
            "bulk": {
                "type": "fixed",
                "size": 32,
                "queue_size": 1000
            },
            "search": {
                "type": "fixed",
                "size": 96,
                "queue_size": 1000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To apply them permanently, replace `transient` with `permanent`. Note that you can also set individual settings transiently or permanently by grouping them accordingly in the cluster update command.

Comment: Should i take backup of my cluster before i apply? can i revert them back? @bsarkar

Comment: Well, taking a backup always helps and yes you can change the settings again.

Comment: will try that now and will let you know @bsarkar

Comment: Ok it works but unfortunately my problem still persist, do you recommend anything to do? i still see **search.rejected** is increasing and i don't get the result on Kibana @bsarkar

Comment: It's 'persistent' in the new version, not 'permanet' any more.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of getting, setting, and clearing transient cluster settings...

```
GET /_cluster/settings?include_defaults=true

GET /_cluster/settings

PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "transient":{ "cluster.routing.allocation.cluster_concurrent_rebalance":0 }
}

PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  // set to null to clear
  "transient":{ "cluster.routing.allocation.cluster_concurrent_rebalance":null }
}
```

These reference are worth a look:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-get-settings.html
- https://logz.io/blog/elasticsearch-cheat-sheet/