# Elasticsearch on AWS: How to fix unassigned shards?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, sharding, elasticsearch-5

I have an index on AWS Elasticsearch which were unassighed due to `NODE_LEFT`. Here's an output of `_cat/shards`

```
rawindex-2017.07.04                     1 p STARTED    
rawindex-2017.07.04                     3 p UNASSIGNED NODE_LEFT
rawindex-2017.07.04                     2 p STARTED    
rawindex-2017.07.04                     4 p STARTED    
rawindex-2017.07.04                     0 p STARTED
```

under normal circumstances, it would be easy to reassign these shards by using the `_cluster` or `_settings`. However, these are the exact APIs that are not allowed by AWS. I get the following message:

```
{
    Message: "Your request: '/_settings' is not allowed."
}
```

According to [an answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20010544/3566440), I can change the setting of an index using `_index` API, which is allowed by AWS. However, it seems like `index.routing.allocation.disable_allocation` is not valid for Elasticsearch 5.x, which I am running. I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "remote_transport_exception",
                "reason": "[enweggf][x.x.x.x:9300][indices:admin/settings/update]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "unknown setting [index.routing.allocation.disable_allocation] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I tried prioritizing index recovery with high `index.priority` as well as setting `index.unassigned.node_left.delayed_timeout` to 1 minute, but I am just not being able to reassign them.

Is there any way (dirty or elegant) to achieve this on AWS managed ES?

Thanks!

Comment: With AWS ES and its limited flexibility, one way I would fix this, if there is already a backup of this index, is to just delete the index and restore it from backup. All shards will be allocated.

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar issue with AWS Elasticsearch version 6.3, namely 2 shards failed to be assigned, and the cluster had status RED. Running `GET _cluster/allocation/explain` showed that the reason was that they had exceeded the default maximum allocation retries of 5.

Running the query `GET <my-index-name>/_settings` revealed the few settings that can be changed per index. Note that all queries are in Kibana format which you have out of the box if you are using AWS Elasticsearch service. The following solved my problem:

```
PUT <my-index-name>/_settings
{
  "index.allocation.max_retries": 6
}
```

Running `GET _cluster/allocation/explain` immediately afterwards returned an error with the following: `"reason": "unable to find any unassigned shards to explain..."`, and after some time the problem was resolved.

Comment: Outstanding. Fixed my problem. One note: you can use the same `GET _cluster/allocation/explain` call to determine which index/indices contain the unassigned nodes in question.

Comment: Is there a way to set this globally?

Comment: Haven't tried this one specifically, but you can use the pseudo-index `_all` to change a setting for all indexes, i.e. `PUT _all/_settings`

Comment: @villasv The error messages from `_cluster/allocation/explain` says you can retry allocation globally on all failed allocations by calling `/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true`. 
I didn't try it personally as I was in a hurry to get my cluster fixed and I only had few indices with failure, so updated retry count on each index .

Answer (score 3):

There might be an alternative solution when the other solutions fail. If you have a managed Elasticsearch Instance on AWS the chances are high that you can "just" restore a snapshot.

### Check for failed indexes.

You can use for e.g.:

```
curl -X GET "https://<es-endpoint>/_cat/shards"
```

or

```
curl -X GET "https://<es-endpoint>/_cluster/allocation/explain"
```

---

### Check for snapshots.

To find snapshot repositories execute the following query:

```
curl -X GET "https://<es-endpoint>/_snapshot?pretty"
```

Next let's have a look at all the snapshots in the `cs-automated` repository:

```
curl -X GET "https://<es-endpoint>/_snapshot/cs-automated/_all?pretty"
```

Find a snapshot where `failures: [ ]` is empty or the index you want to restore is NOT in a failed state. Then delete the index you want to restore:

```
curl -XDELETE 'https://<es-endpoint>/<index-name>'
```

... and restore the deleted index like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'https://<es-endpoint>/_snapshot/cs-automated/<snapshot-name>/_restore' -d '{"indices": "<index-name>"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

There is also some good documentation here:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html#es-managedomains-snapshot-restore
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-handling-errors.html#aes-handling-errors-red-cluster-status

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem. The solution is pretty simple. You can solve it in 2 different ways.

First solution is to edit all indexes collectively:

```
PUT _all/_settings
{
    "index.allocation.max_retries": 3
}
```

Second solution is to edit specific indexes:

```
PUT <myIndex>/_settings
{
    "index.allocation.max_retries": 3
}
```